# Creating a table of points for a 3D Plot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Suppose $X$ can take integer values from 0 to 10. Suppose further that $Y$ is continuous from 0 to 1. Finally, let us define $Z = X\,Y$.

I now want to create a table that contains values of $Z$ by incrementing $Y$ from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.01 and $X$ from 0 to 10 in steps of 1. The purpose is to draw a 3D plot.

This example is a boiled-down version of a problem I am working on.

Comment: Take a look at [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html), that should solve your problem. Or you could just directly use [`Plot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot3D.html) and not worry about explicit discretization.

Answer (score 4):

The easy way to make your table is:

```
pts = Table[{x, y, x y}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 1, .1}] // Catenate;
```

Then you can plot it like so:

```
ListPlot3D[pts]
```

[image: plot]

Note that I decreased the granularity of the `y` data to 0.1; For plotting, finer granularity doesn't really result in any improvement.

Answer (score 0):

```
z[x_, y_]: = x*y

data3d = Join@@Table[{x, y, z[x, y]}, {x, 0, 10, 1}, {y, 0, 1, 0.01}];

ListPlot3D[data3d]
```